# Como chamar e exibir um Janela WPF que está em uma dll

Tags: c#, wpf

Tenho uma `DLL` contendo uma janela WPF, criada através de um projeto do tipo `WPF User Control Library`.
Como faço para exibir essa janela a partir de um outro projeto?

XAML da janela (projeto DLL):

```
<Window x:Class="UmaJanelaComUmBotao.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UmaJanelaComUmBotao"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,55,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Código C# da janela (projeto DLL):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace UmaJanelaComUmBotao
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Lógica interna para Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1 ( )
        {
            InitializeComponent ( );
        }
    }
}
```

Se for necessário o codebehind posso está postando também.

Método main (projeto .exe)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UmaJanelaComUmBotao;

namespace OExcutavel
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main ( string[ ] args )
        {
            //Como chamar Window1 a partir daqui
        }
    }
}
```

codebehind:

```
namespace UmaJanelaComUmBotao {


    /// <summary>
    /// Window1
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : System.Windows.Window, System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector {


        #line 10 "..\..\Window1.xaml"
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1823:AvoidUnusedPrivateFields")]
        internal System.Windows.Controls.Button button;

        #line default
        #line hidden

        private bool _contentLoaded;

        /// <summary>
        /// InitializeComponent
        /// </summary>
        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
        public void InitializeComponent() {
            if (_contentLoaded) {
                return;
            }
            _contentLoaded = true;
            System.Uri resourceLocater = new System.Uri("/UmaJanelaComUmBotao;component/window1.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);

            #line 1 "..\..\Window1.xaml"
            System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceLocater);

            #line default
            #line hidden
        }

        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
        [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Design", "CA1033:InterfaceMethodsShouldBeCallableByChildTypes")]
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Maintainability", "CA1502:AvoidExcessiveComplexity")]
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1800:DoNotCastUnnecessarily")]
        void System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector.Connect(int connectionId, object target) {
            switch (connectionId)
            {
            case 1:
            this.button = ((System.Windows.Controls.Button)(target));
            return;
            }
            this._contentLoaded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tentou um `new App().Run();`? Tem um `App.Xaml` configurado? O `StartupUri` está com o `Window1`?

Comment: Pior que não, não tentei nada disso, não sei nem por onde começar, toda a literatura não aborda em como fazer isso assim. Geralmente sempre deixam que a IDE gere tudo.
Eu não tenho um App.xaml pq o projeto do executável é do tipo `Console Application`.
Tenho uma linha referente a URI no codebehind, vou editar e postar o mesmo.

Comment: WPF e Console não combinam.

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva, você já gerou a DLL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para isso funcionar você deve fazer os seguintes passos:

1º - Adicione as seguintes referencias no projeto console: `PresentationFramework`, `WindowBase` e `PresentationCore`.

2º - Deve adicionar a referencia a `DLL` que você criou, caso você já tenha criado a `DLL`.

Fiz um teste básico com este código e está funcionando:

```
using System;
using WpfApplication4;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
  class Program
  {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
        main.ShowDialog();
    }
  }
}
```

Segue imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte: [Aqui](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ff202e87-5829-47eb-8098-9b5786df9d37/open-a-fully-prepared-wpf-window-from-console?forum=wpf), [aqui](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b28a4265-be2c-4e2f-b71f-aeddcd85bcf1/how-to-convert-a-wpf-windows-application-to-dll?forum=netfxbcl) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715554/the-calling-thread-must-be-sta-because-many-ui-components-require-this-error-in).

Comment: Vou testar e dou o feedback.

Comment: Sim, marquei como respondido pois realmente funcionou. Mas não era bem esse resultado que eu tinha em mente.
Ao executar, uma janela de console é aberta junto com a janela, e eu não queria isso. Provavelmente é devido ao projeto do tipo console como o @bigown citou.
Minha ideia é deixar todo o front-end da aplicação fora do executável, ou seja, dentro de uma `dll`.
O executável deve ser "burro", servindo apenas para startar a aplicação. bac-kend e front-end ficariam em `dlls`.
Por isso pensei em um projeto console, pois é o executável mais básico que existe.

Comment: Entendi, da uma pesquisas sobre projeto em camadas, aí você vai conseguir fazer o que querendo. Resumindo grosseiramente, você cria uma projeto "exe" com wpf, e outro projeto do tipo biblioteca de classes com suas regras de negócios.

Comment: Entendi, eu já conheço o modelo de camadas, mas nesse caso que você cita o front-end ou ao menos parte dele (Janela Principal, ou um splash) ficaria no executável assim fugiria da minha ideia que é ter 0 GUI no executável. GUI e regras de negócios ficariam em `DLLs` distintas. A maioria das pessoas usa o trivial que é a GUI empacotada com o executável.
Mas estou começando a achar que é impossível fugir disso.

Comment: Acho que talvez o caminho seja [esse](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25381844/5913854), ou seja, realmente o tal arquivo App.xaml como citou o **bigown** citou.

Comment: Encontrei um material que pode ajudar: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/wpf-application/working-with-app-xaml/